# reSolve and React Native integration

Tags: react-native, cqrs, event-sourcing, resolvejs

Is there any working example available involving [reSolve](https://reimagined.github.io/resolve/) in React Native?
Suggestions of comparable solutions (running without any back-end connectivity in place) either in React Native or Flutter are also most appreciated.

GitHub contains an example in the [reimagined/react-native-example](https://github.com/reimagined/react-native-example) repository but unfortunately it isn't working. It seems the current version is pretty outdated.

Referring to that repository, the command `yarn create resolve-app -e shopping-list-advanced shopping-list-advanced` results in the following error message.

> Error: No such example, shopping-list-advanced. The following examples are available

So you are unable to download the sample code since it does not appear to exist.

So I tried downloading and inflating the ZIP manually. Afterwards I ran `yarn install` (which takes a while and reports quite a lot of warnings). Next, I used the command `yarn start:native`. This doesn't work either and results in the following error message.

> ERROR: Node.js version 16.13.2 is no longer supported.
> expo-cli supports following Node.js versions: 
> >=10.13.0 <11.0.0 (Active LTS) 
> >=12.0.0 <13.0.0 (Active LTS) 
> >=13.0.0 <14.0.0 (Current Release)

In an attempt to solve the problem, I updated the expo-cli version in the native\package.json file to 5.0.3. Running `yarn install` and `yarn start:native` again results in a new error message being thrown error.

> Invalid regular expression:
> /(ui[\]node_modules[\]react-native[\].*|ui[\]node_modules[\]expo[\].*|node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\**tests**\.*)$/:
> Range out of order in character class.

This doesn't seem to go anywhere... In other words, I am a bit stuck here since I don't know what this message actually means.

Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The team decided to extract the React Native example to a separate repository and postpone its maintenance to keep focused on more important tasks like polishing the server-side.

As you mentioned, the example is outdated, there are many changes in the client configuration since then. In the future, we may work on some guide on how to use reSolve in React Native and other frameworks.

In the meantime, you can try to add reSolve in your ReactNative app using our docs.

We provide several client libraries that can be helpful:
https://reimagined.github.io/resolve/docs/api/client/resolve-client/
https://reimagined.github.io/resolve/docs/api/client/resolve-react-hooks/
https://reimagined.github.io/resolve/docs/api/client/resolve-redux/

Feel free to contact us through Github in case of any difficulties, we'll be glad to help you.